# [error]Cmd.exe exited with code '-4058' (TestCafe Integration with Azure Pipeline)

Tags: testing, azure-devops, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I got this error when I run the job for 'run testcafe' in the azure release pipeline. The package.json is in the same folder as the project but it still show this error.
[image]

Comment: Please ensure you also provide the error in text so it's easier to read, copy and paste for those who want to help you.

Comment: I will remember this in future. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that the `D:\a\r1\a\package.json` file was not found. Correct the Azure Pipeline so that the executable file points to the existing file.

Comment: I've found the solution. Thanks :)